# How to use FormControl in angular2 to get comma separated values from INPUT tag?

Tags: angular, typescript

here is my  alert-form.component.ts

```
export class AlertFormComponent  implements OnInit{

  ....
  pages:FBpage[]=[]; 

 .....
```

And in the constructor:

```
 fbPage : new FormControl('')
```

and in html:

`<input mdInput placeholder="Page Facebook" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="fbPage" >`

but obviously it gets just one value not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the FormControl make sure the blank value is an empty array, rather than '' or undefined.

In the constructor declare like this:

```
fbPage : new FormControl([]);
```

instead of

```
fbPage : new FormControl('');
```

Edit: You've to bind data to a list to get comma separated values from input tag as mentioned below.

```
<input [source]="pageList" ...... >
```

in typescript class:

```
public pageList = [
"PageA", "PageB"
];
```

This article might help you:
https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete/issues/91

Comment: thank's I'll try it, please tell me, what makes know that the input is gonna come separated with commas ?